# Is it ok to bin residuals before examining them?

Tags: regression, residuals

I'm analyzing the residuals from a regression model fit to a dataset that covers several years worth of data.  I want to report the sum of the residuals from that model, by year, as a measure of how the overall error for each year changes over time.

Is this an acceptable way to report residuals?

Here is an example of my calculation:

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(1)
Year <- c(  rep(2007,12),
            rep(2008,12),
            rep(2009,12),
            rep(2010,12),
            rep(2011,12))
n <- length(Year)
index <- 1:n
A <- (index+5*rnorm(n))^2+5*rnorm(n)
P <- predict(lm(A~Year),data.frame(A,Year))

residual <- A-P
residual2 <- ddply(data.frame(Year,residual),'Year',sum)

plot(2007+(index-7)/12,residual)
lines(residual2$Year,residual2$residual,col=2)

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(index,residual)
plot(residual2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Acceptable" is a subjective matter, and you are entitled to present your result in any way you choose. However, note that a standard assumption to regression analysis is that your data is independent and identically distributed, and in order to measure the quality of your regression model, one usually look at the residual. Good residuals, don't change over time, (stationary), and you will know that your model is not adequate if your residual is not stationary (i.e. changes over time)..

So in short, you can summarize/present the residual anyway you like, however, if you show that the residual changes over time, then you would have shown that the model is not good (ie. you can not use the standard inferences regarding the coefficient estimate of your model)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm examining the residuals over time to make sure they are independent.  If they vary over time, I'll know there's a problem with the model.

Comment: Subjective or not, the sum is not generally meaningful, because it depends on how many residuals occur per year, which might be a quantity wholly unrelated to anything of interest.  At a minimum, look at the *mean* residual by year.  Better yet, look at the *mean square*.  This will reveal both time-related changes and possible heteroscedasticity.

Comment: to Zach: While a visual display of data is very good for presentation, you might not get the accurate picture when looking at the plot. A better way to test the above assumptions, is to do a specialized statistical test. The following [link](http://www.duke.edu/~rnau/testing.htm) discuss how to detect when the assumptions of linear regression are not valid, and what to do in that case.